# CONSUME ANTIMALWARE SCAN INTERFACE (AMSI) FROM C# in windows 2008 R2 or 2016

Tags: .net-core, virus-scanning

I am working with (AMSI) in Dotnet core API to scan the virus-infected file and it is working fine with windows 10 But on production, We have windows 2008r2 and it does not provide the (AMSI).

So is that possible to use (AMSI) on server 2008 r2 or any other windows server edition.

Answer (score 1):

AMSI is first available on Windows Server 2016.  For earlier versions you need to use a different solution, possibly Windows Defender directly but more likely the API published by a particular anti-malware vendor.